# ViewAdapter is not abstract and does not override abstract method onBindRealmViewHolder(ViewAdapter.ViewHolder,int) in RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: java, overriding, abstract-class

I have added code below,While Android Studio doesn't show any error, but compiler raise this error.
If we have a look at code, the abstract method is overridden which is not seen by the compiler.

**Parent Class** (Code is from a library and not my own)

```
public abstract class RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter
    <T extends RealmModel, VH extends RealmViewHolder>
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RealmViewHolder> 
{
    ...
    public abstract void onBindRealmViewHolder(VH holder, int position);
}
```

Now I'm writing this new Class :

**My Child Class**

```
public class ViewAdapter <T extends RealmModel> 
extends RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter<T , ViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
{

    @Override
    public void onBindRealmViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i)
    {
        RealmModel modelObject = realmResults.get(i);
        //... some Code
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RealmViewHolder
    {
         // ViewHolder code ....
    }

}
```

Error :

> Error:(28, 8) error: ViewAdapter is not abstract and does not override abstract method onBindRealmViewHolder(ViewAdapter.ViewHolder,int) in RealmBasedRecyclerViewAdapter
>
> Error:(65, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype